# Is the singleton pattern still bad when we talk about it in a framework context?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, singleton

Using the singleton pattern is usually a code smell.

However, it seems that using "singletons" in a framework such as Laravel is a popular solution to a lot of problems.

It's also worth noting that singletons in Laravel aren't really the same thing as a singleton class in the following sense:

- The class being used as a singleton is unaware of this, there are no
  static methods in there, nor is there anything that would prevent you
  from creating a new instance of that class manually.
- When using Laravel singletons, the container keeps track of the
  objects you want to use as singleton and hands these to you upon
  request.

Am I correct in my understanding that what is called a singleton in Laravel isn't in fact a singleton, but an implementation inspired by the singleton pattern, and therefore isn't as much as a bad practice as a real singleton because it gets rid of some of the downsides (harder to test, global state...)?

This question is loosely related to [this question about design patterns in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222960/what-patterns-can-be-used-to-avoid-duplicate-database-queries-during-a-request) but it appeared appropriate to me to create a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is still bad. It is still an anti-pattern.

The fact, that you see many people resorting to this, simply indicate the flaws in any given system. It applies to applications, frameworks and libraries.

And saying that *"our singletons are different"* is just wrong. And, if you were writing proper unit tests, you would be testing your code in **isolation**, without having to initialize various parts of a framework.

> <sub>**P.S.**
>
>   You seem to have wrong opinion of what "code smell" is. Code smell is when you have variables named `$a1`, `$bzzzz`, code smell is when your functions have 8 parameters. Anit-pattern is not a code smell. It is a mistake in architecture.</sub>

Comment: I don't see an issue in testing a class that is bound as a singleton in a DI container in isolation. Your implementations shouldn't care what instance they are receiving.

Comment: I'd argue against this answer. It really depends on how you use them in laravel. What you call a singleton in laravel is an object in a dependency injection container. If you let the DI container handle the injection into the class constructor, I really don't see any harm in using them. Using the `app()` or `App::make()` helpers for this however is a bigger issue, as these do introduce a tight coupling to the application itself.